# Выбора mysql left join

Tags: php, mysql

где ошибся?
нужно вывести сумму товаров по месяцам за 2019 год

```
modx_ms2_orders - таблица заказов
modx_ms2_order_products - товары из таблицы заказов
modx_site_content - список ресурсов, здесь идет ограничение по родителю
```

на данный момент он ищет сумму по всем заказам, без учета `mc.parent`

```
SELECT SUM(mp.cost) as cost, MONTH(mo.createdon) as m FROM `modx_ms2_orders` mo 
left join `modx_ms2_order_products` mp on mp.order_id = mo.id 
left JOIN `modx_site_content` mc on mc.id=mp.product_id and mc.parent=81 
WHERE DATE_FORMAT(mo.`createdon`, '%Y') = 2019 GROUP by MONTH(mo.createdon)
```

Comment: left join предназначен специально для поиска записей, для которых что то может не найтись в правой таблице, т.е. как раз для того что бы выбрать вообще все из первой таблицы. Для ваших целей слово left из обоих join надо убрать

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT SUM(mp.cost) as cost, MONTH(mo.createdon) as m 
FROM `modx_ms2_orders` mo 
INNER JOIN `modx_ms2_order_products` mp on mp.order_id = mo.id 
INNER JOIN `modx_site_content` mc on mc.id=mp.product_id and mc.parent=81 
WHERE 
DATE_FORMAT(mo.`createdon`, '%Y') = 2019 GROUP by MONTH(mo.createdon)
```